# What is the link between superfluids and BEC?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

i’m studying superfluids (in particular $^4 He$) and one of the first theorical apporoach was with Bose-Einstein condensation and i know that we can calculate the $T_c$ and it is close to the the experimental value, even if $^4 He$ is not a diluite boson gas. Moreover we use Hartee-Fock that assume that all the particels are in the fundamental state that in some way it is linked with bec. But in general what is the link between superfluids and bec? In general what we can say about superfluids and bec?